# Problem installing tor on Kali Linux

Tags: apt, kali-linux, tor

I'm trying to install `tor` on my Kali Linux 2016.1 (`kali-rolling`). When I type `apt-get install tor` in Terminal, this error appears:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package tor is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'tor' has no installation candidate
```

How can I fix this and install tor?

UPD:

I tried this: http://www.blackmoreops.com/2013/12/16/installing-tor-kali-linux/ - I added `deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org wheezy main` to sources file, but it didn't help at all, so I deleted this string and now it's in a default condition

Comment: What Kali version?

Comment: @Will 2016.1, latest version

Comment: Can you show `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: So far, I'm going to suggest running: `apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y` which should get  `apt` and your system packages up to date.

Comment: @Will, see my updated answer. I tried this, no change at all

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, `kali-rolling` has `tor` already supposedly, so adding the `torproject.org` repository shouldn't be needed. One more thing we should check; `apt-cache rdepends tor` so we can see what the other package that references `tor` is. And showing sources.list would still help.

Comment: I'm surprised that `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y && sudo apt-get install tor` as isn't working though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution:

Firstly, I ran:

```
echo -e "deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib\ndeb http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ sana/updates main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and then

```
apt-get update
apt-get update --fix-missing
```

After this Tor was installed normally with `apt-get install tor`.