# Package "packagename" has no installation candidate in Kali 2.0

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

I installed Kali 2.0 and when I try to install anything (ex :software-center) I have this problem:

> apt-get install software-center 
>   Reading package lists... Done Building
>   dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Package
>   software-center is not available, but is referred to by another
>   package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate

this is the first action I did when I installed ..

By the way I filled the `/etc/apt/source.list` by what I find in Kali page
then I used

```
apt-get update
```

and

```
apt-get upgrade
```

and

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

the `source.list` has :

```
#Regular repositories deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main
contrib non-free
# Source repositories deb-src http.kali. org/kali sana main non-free contrib deb-src security.kali. org/kali-security
sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

(I deleted "http" word here cause I haven't the right to post more than two links yet)

there where nothing to upgrade or to update (because I downloaded Kali yesterday from official website?)

Any help please?

Comment: What does `source.list` look like? What other packages have you tried to install? Were the update and upgrade successful?

Comment: I edited the post and the update and the upgrade where both successful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

Firstly, I ran:

```
echo -e "deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib\ndeb http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ sana/updates main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and then

```
apt-get update 
apt-get update --fix-missing
```

it is right here :
[Problem installing tor on Kali Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259592/problem-installing-tor-on-kali-linux)

Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

kali-rolling is the current active repository since the release of Kali 2016.1. The following entries should be in `sources.list`:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```