# apt-get install not working

Tags: apt, kali-linux

here is what the machine shows

```
#apt-get install tor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package tor is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'tor' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: Look at this answer. It might help you. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259605/237568

Comment: im using kali linux Sir

Comment: apt-get update && apt-cache search tor && apt-get install tor

Comment: The are some bug (temporary) on the kali-linux repository , now  you can update and install your packages without problem

Answer (score 0):

On [Debian/Ubuntu](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en) you need previously add correct sources in /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org stretch main
deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org stretch main
```

After this you should run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install tor
```

**For Kali Linux read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259592/problem-installing-tor-on-kali-linux) topic.**